# Indefinite Integration of $\frac {2}{x^2}-\frac 1{2x^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The question is to find the integral of this:

$$\int\left(\frac 2{x^2}-\frac 1{2x^3}\right)\, dx$$

I get basic integration but I'm not sure about how to hand the $2x^3$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone should know, not only $$\int x^{n}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\quad (n\in \mathbf R,\; n\ne- 1),$$
but also the ‘denominator form’:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^n}=-\frac1{(n-1)\mkern1mux^{n-1}}\quad(n\in \mathbf R,\; n\ne  1). $$
Knowing that, you obtain readily
$$\int\biggl(\frac 2{x^2}-\frac 1{2x^3}\biggr)\,\mathrm dx=2\int\frac {\mathrm dx}{x^2}-\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^3}=-\frac2x+\frac12\frac1{2\mkern1mu x^2}=\frac{1-2x}{4x^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write your Integrand in the form
$$2x^{-2}-\frac{1}{2}x^{-3}$$ and use that $$\int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$ if $$n\neq -1$$

Comment: Thank you Dr. Graubner, And @Crescendo I am aware which is why i asked for ideas not an answer, as you can see above the hint was the form of the intergrand, which is what i couldn't do. You are here to help which is what i asked for, the hint isnt the answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your compliment! And my Name is Sonnhard

Comment: oh @Crescendo i meant to put in what i got fro my answer and say so you get:answer but i couldnt figure out how to do the fractions and powers on here